# OWA crash in e.importFromSeriesTimeJsonObject when Add-In requests recurrence data

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

New Outlook calendar entry.  Set recurring (e.g. daily for a few days) and launch the Outlook Add-In.

Outlook Add-In code:

```
const stLocal: Date = await GetOutlookTimeAsync(this.OutlookEvent.start);
const edLocal: Date = await GetOutlookTimeAsync(this.OutlookEvent.end);
const recurrence: Office.Recurrence = await GetOutlookStructureAsync("recurrence", this.OutlookEvent.recurrence);
```

..snip..

```
export const GetOutlookStructureAsync = (func: string, evt: any) => {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    const who: string = "GetOutlookStructure " + func;
    DebugLog(who, "Start");
    evt.getAsync((asyncResult: Office.AsyncResult<any>) => {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        DebugLog(who, JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value));
        resolve(asyncResult.value);
      } else {
        const errorText: string = asyncResult.error.message;
        DebugLog(who, errorText);
        reject(new Error(errorText));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Browser console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startYear' of undefined
 at e.importFromSeriesTimeJsonObject (outlook-web-16.01.js:19)
 at Ta (outlook-web-16.01.js:19)
 at (outlook-web-16.01.js:19)
 at Object.a [as callback]  (outlook-web-16.01.js:19)
 at L (outlook-web-16.01.js:19)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is currently being tracked here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1312